# display: flex breaks <li> element with Text and HTML-Tags like <strong> inside

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'am currently running into a problem with display: flex when using it on a `<li>` Element with Text and HTML-Tags like `<strong>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>` and so on. `display: flex` is used to position the custom bullet points to the text and to hide the default bullet points with overwrite the default `display: list-item` with `display: flex`.

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #878787;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <strong>amet eirmod tempor</strong> invidunt</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <u>amet</u> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <i>diam nonumy</i> eirmod tempor invidunt</li>
  <li>Element without any Tags only plain Text - no Error</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see in the snippet the spaces before and after the HTML-Tag get lost, even if there are still spaces before the strong, u and i tags in the text.

If you few it on mobile the text just breaks lines in the middle of the text. Some of the text before the HTML-Tag just goes to the second row while some of the text after it stays in the first row.

Only fix i found so far is putting `<p>`Tags inside the `<li>` Elements like

```
<li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <strong>amet eirmod tempor</strong> invidunt</p></li>
```

But thats not realy an Option for me.
When using Wordpress for example, you have to go the Code View inside the Text-Editor to place the `<p>` Tag inside the `<li>`. When switching back to the Visuell View the `<p>` Tag gets removed by Wordpress.

Using `&nbsp` (as suggested by @Simone Rossaini) also causes the Text to break wrong

How can this be fixed and why does display: flex even affect the text inside the `<li>` in first place?

EDIT: For better understanding i added the li:before for the custom bullet points

Comment: Gold rule: never ever use flexbox as a container for text. Flexbox is for boxes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&nbsp;` for create space without use `<p>` tag:

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit&nbsp;<strong>amet eirmod tempor</strong>&nbsp;invidunt</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <u>amet</u> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <i>diam nonumy</i> eirmod tempor invidunt</li>
  <li>Element without any Tags only plain Text - no Error</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. The Problem with this is that the Text still jumps rows when viewed in mobile. If you check the first Text "dolor sit" is just placed in the second row and therefore breaks the Text which would make it impossible for users to read

Answer (score 0):

**Just removed the `display: flex` from `li`, will solve the problem.**

> By default `li` element has style `display: list-item` to display as
>   `bullet`, and `list-style-type` is used to style appearance of `li`
>   (E.g: `disc`, `circle`, `decimal`)

If you don't want to display bullet before `li` then make it as `display: inline-block;`